# How can I avoid my very big nested for-loops?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I have to implement some simulations using Physical formulas. In one formula, there are many variables. And I want to vary those variables with 100 samples. And for each sample, I have to calculate using all the combinations. The simplified for-loop better explains what I want to do:

```
set.seed(3)
a = rnorm(100)
b = rnorm(100)
c = rnorm(100)
d = rnorm(100)
f = rnorm(100)

for (a in 1:length(a)) {
        
        for (b in 1:length(b)) {
                
                for (c in 1:length(c)) {
                        
                        for (d in 1:length(d)) {
                                
                                for (f in 1:length(f)) {
                                        
                                        value = a + b / c * d - f # for illustrative purposes only
                                        # .... 
                                        # ... then I append the value to a vector etc.
                                        
                                }
                                
                        }
                        
                }
                
        }
        
}
```

As you can see, when the number of parameters to be varied (100 samples for each parameter) increases, number of simulations increases exponentially, so does computation time. I have to vary 10-15 parameters and calculate the "value" for all the combinations of parameters. Is there any way (at all) that I can avoid these loops? What is a good programming habit to have when dealing with large computations like this?

Comment: Your code would generate a vector of 100 ^ 5 = 10e5 values. Are you sure that’s what you want? It’s a prohibitively large number, and the vector would take up more than 37 GiB of RAM.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I am generating synthetic data and for my task, the more data I can generate, the more it will help me solve the problem I am working on. I can access unusually good computer, so computer power is not a big deal. However, the current for-loop approach of mine is not attractive and I feel like there should be a much better way of solving this problem.

Comment: Throwing more data at a problem can only get you so far: exhaustive searches are of very limited usefulness, that’s why they’re done so rarely, even with beefy hardware. — That said, you should look at R’s matrix operations; in particular, `outer`. Using this function, you can get rid of *all* the loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you’re doing is essentially create a large multi-dimensional array of permutations with some given operations, and flatten the result.

The permutation array can be created using [`outer`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/help/outer.html): for example, `` outer(a, b, `+`) `` is an array of all the pairwise combinations of `a[i] + b[j]`. The whole array is given by (attention to operator precedence!):

```
array = outer(outer(a, outer(outer(b, c, `/`), d), `+`), f, `-`)
```

(Alternatively, `outer(a, b)`, which is the same as `` outer(a, b, `*`) ``, can also be written as `a %o% b`.)

To flatten the array, use `as.vector`:

```
value = as.vector(array)
```

The result is the same as that using the `expand.grid`. the difference is that using `expand.grid` is more readable:

```
value = with(expand.grid(a = a, b = b, c = c, d = d, f = f), a + b / c * d - f)
```

… but *substantially slower*, and uses *a lot* more memory.

We could increase the readability of the array permutations by creating custom operators:

```
make_outer = function (f) function (a, b) outer(a, b, f)
`%o+%` = make_outer(`+`)
`%o-%` = make_outer(`-`)
`%o/%` = make_outer(`/`)

value = as.vector(a %o+% ((b %o/% c) %o% d) %o-% f)
```

Comment: I benchmarked it with the small set from my answer and the `expand_grid` method takes about 6-7 times longer and uses twice the memory.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `expand.grid` to define all combinations before calculation:

```r
set.seed(3)
a = rnorm(10)
b = rnorm(10)
c = rnorm(10)
d = rnorm(10)
f = rnorm(10)

# find all possible combinations
sets <- expand.grid(
  a = a,
  b = b,
  c = c,
  d = d,
  f = f
)

# calculations is quick and vectorised
value <-  sets$a + sets$b / sets$c * sets$d - sets$f
head(value)
#> [1] -0.58891116  0.08049653  0.63181047 -0.77910963  0.56880508  0.40314620
```

Not necessary but somewhat nicer-looking in `tidyverse`

```r
library(tidyverse)
sets %>% 
  mutate(value = a + b / c * d - f) %>% 
  as_tibble() # just for nicer printing
#> # A tibble: 100,000 x 6
#>          a      b      c     d     f   value
#>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 -0.962  -0.745 -0.578 0.901 0.787 -0.589 
#>  2 -0.293  -0.745 -0.578 0.901 0.787  0.0805
#>  3  0.259  -0.745 -0.578 0.901 0.787  0.632 
#>  4 -1.15   -0.745 -0.578 0.901 0.787 -0.779 
#>  5  0.196  -0.745 -0.578 0.901 0.787  0.569 
#>  6  0.0301 -0.745 -0.578 0.901 0.787  0.403 
#>  7  0.0854 -0.745 -0.578 0.901 0.787  0.458 
#>  8  1.12   -0.745 -0.578 0.901 0.787  1.49  
#>  9 -1.22   -0.745 -0.578 0.901 0.787 -0.846 
#> 10  1.27   -0.745 -0.578 0.901 0.787  1.64  
#> # … with 99,990 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>